# で usage in this sentence

Tags: particle-で

英雄はただ、1人でいい。 This sentence, What does it mean. I got 2 meanings in my mind.

1.) Hero is just one person. (Only one hero is enough)

2.) Hero is one person and good. (Hero is one good person)

Which one is correct here ? And why is it ? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think the `でいい` here means **"it's ok to...", "There's no problem in..."**

So, I believe "Only one hero is enough" is a good translation if there's context for that, like if the person who got answered that said before that "one person/here is not enough", etc.

I would interpret it as either:

> **It's ok for a hero to be just one person.**
>
> **Only one hero is enough.**

Depending on the context.

Here's another example:

> Person1: **アイスクリームを食{た}べたい。I want to eat ice cream.**
>
> Person2: **まあ、今{き}日{よう}スーパーに行く予{よ}定{てい}はない... Well, I have no plans of going to the supermarket today...**
>
> Person1: **コンビニのアイスでいいよ。Hey, it could be a convenience store ice cream (I don't mind)**